# Django migrations fail in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-migrations

I'm trying to deploy a Django (1.8) app to Heroku, runtime Python 3.4.2. The app runs succesfully (except the fact that tables are not created), but when trying run the syncdb I get the following error:

```
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.5851
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management       
/commands/syncdb.py:24: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The syncdb command 
will be removed in Django 1.9
warnings.warn("The syncdb command will be removed in Django 1.9", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 157, in check_key
return list(self.graph.root_nodes(key[0]))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django /core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
call_command("migrate", **options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
self.build_graph()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 287, in build_graph
parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 164, in check_key
raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: authentication
```

I'm using sqlite.

Comment: Is `authentication` in your installed apps?

Comment: yes, the authentication is in installed apps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your dev machine, create your migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations`. Then, assuming your migrations folders are pushed to heroku, on heroku run `python manage.py migrate` instead of `python manage.py syncdb`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#workflow).

Comment: I am having the same problem. What do I do with migrations for django apps that are in my virtualenv? Maybe that's not my problem anyway, I'm not sure.

Comment: Try heroku run python manage.py migrate. This will migrate the apps in your production machine's virtualenv.

Answer (score 7):

I hade to enter the heroku's machine **bash** :

`heroku run bash`

and then make the `makemigrations`:

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
```

Finally,

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

For me i solved this issue by using same command what we use in our local server with prefix "heroku run" that's it..

for eg:-

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

it will work in our local but for heroku, like this :-

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
```