# Deploying Django App on Heroku using Windows

Tags: django, heroku

I want to deploy my django app on heroku , which I have built on Windows machine.

Can I deploy the same application using heroku toolbelt for windows.

Or I have to setup all the things on a unix machine.

And one more thing the application uses Python 3 and Django 1.8

Will that be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There aren't any special process listed in the docs for windows users</strike>You should actually deploy from a unix environment, you have to create your `Procfile`, `requirements.txt` and make some changes to your settings.py file, it's easy and straight forward.

A step by step guide can be found here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

Some problems you may encouter:
[Internal Server Error heroku/django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729515/internal-server-error-heroku-django)
[Django migrations fail in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732411/django-migrations-fail-in-heroku)

Also make sure you add your migrations and **cache** folders to your .gitignore file.